# My string set using UserDefaults coming up as nil when I try to access it

Tags: ios, swift, label, nsuserdefaults, textfield

[image: main.storyboard]

As my code below shows...

When I press the save button, it saves textfield input to user defaults so I can display it in a label. That works fine, as the label is displayed immediately when I save the input.

I've added a swipe gesture to flip the UIView containing the label and display another image. But when I want to flip it back with the swipe, it shows an error saying the label is now nil??

I am new to this, spare me if it is an easy silly error easily fixed.

Thnx for any help.

ViewController.swift FILE

```
  import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var back: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var plateView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!

var showingFront = true

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    back = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "back.png"))

    let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swiped))
    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    plateView.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "blank.png")!)

    saveBtn.isHidden = true

}


func swiped() {

    if (showingFront) {

        UIView.transition(from: label, to: back, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)

        showingFront = false

    } else {


        UIView.transition(from: back, to: label, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)

        showingFront = true

    }
}


@IBAction func editingDidBegin(_ sender: Any) {

    saveBtn.isHidden = false
    label.isHidden = true
    text.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {

    defaults.set(text.text, forKey: "number")
    defaults.synchronize()
    let num = defaults.string(forKey: "number")
    label.text = num

    label.isHidden = false
    saveBtn.isHidden = true

    view.endEditing(true)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Can you please share the image of your Storyboard/xib to get more clarity.

Comment: done. also updated code so its cleaner and makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code is just a test for now.

Try to synchronize the userDefaults so they get written by the system:

```
defaults.set(text.text, forKey: "number")
defaults.synchronize()

...
```

Furthermore, `defaults.string(forKey: ...)` returns an optional because it may fail for several reasons.

```
if let num = defaults.string(forKey: "number") {
    lab.text = num
}
```

Comment: It works when I press save, because it must if it is displayed in the label. But when I swipe to flip it, and then attempt to swipe again to flip back to the label, it says its nil.